# Prove/disprove number of zeros inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, roots

1. Having a continuous differentiable function $f(x)$, and denote $Z(\cdot)$ number of zeros (assume real line), and $(\cdot)^\prime$ first derivative, I would like to know if following inequality holds:
   $$Z\left(\left(\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f^2(x)}\right)^\prime\right)\leq Z(f^{\prime\prime}(x)).$$

From Rolle's theorem we know that $Z(g(x))\leq Z(g^\prime(x))+1$, meaning that 
$$Z\left(\left(\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f^2(x)}\right)^\prime\right)\leq Z\left(\left(\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f^2(x)}\right)^{\prime\prime}\right)+1.$$
But I don't know how to use this fact.

2. Another question is the following. Is it true that 
   $$Z\left(\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f^2(x)}\right)\leq Z(f^\prime(x))?$$
   My reasoning is that number of zeros are determined only by the nominator ($f^\prime(x)$) and therefore if we divide the function by some other function (e.g. $f^2(x)$) we can in the worst case only remove some of the zeros in nominator, but we can never add new zeros. Is the thinking ok?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are not strong enough: consider the real-valued function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by:
$$f:x\longmapsto\begin{cases}0&\text{if $x=0$}\\\mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2}&\text{if $x\neq0$.}\end{cases}$$
Then for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$:
\begin{align*}
f'(x)&=\begin{cases}0&\text{if $x=0$}\\\dfrac2{x^3}\mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2}&\text{if $x\neq0$}\end{cases}&
f''(x)&=\begin{cases}0&\text{if $x=0$}\\-2\dfrac{3x^2-2}{x^6}\mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2}&\text{if $x\neq0$}\end{cases}\\
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}&=\begin{cases}\text{DNE}&\text{if $x=0$}\\\dfrac2{x^3}\mathrm{e}^{1/x^2}&\text{if $x\neq0$}\end{cases}&
\left(\frac{f'}{f^2}\right)'(x)&=\begin{cases}\text{DNE}&\text{if $x\neq0$}\\-2\dfrac{3x^2+2}{x^6}\mathrm{e}^{1/x^2}&\text{if $x\neq0$}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then $Z\bigl(f''\bigr)=3$ and $Z\left(\left(\dfrac{f'}{f^2}\right)'\right)=0$, so 1 is false.

Comment: Nice counterexample! Thanks. What about the second point?

Comment: @pisoir Your second looks ok (but we're only talking about the points where the function $f'/f^2$ is defined): if $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ is a zero of $f'/f^2$, i.e., $f(x_0)^2\neq0$ and $f'(x_0)=0$, then, obviously, $x_0$ is a zero of $f'$. Hence we conclude that $Z(f'/f^2)\leq Z(f')$.